# JavaScript code or framework for converting columns to rows and rows to columns in HTML table or div grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, pivot-table

I am looking for a script or JavaScript framework plugin which can help me to manipulate HTML grids. On some event call, columns and rows should be interchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple function, assuming that there are exactly n*m cells (no colspans/rowspans, no varying row widths):

```
function translate(tableel) {
    var rows = tableel.rows,
        m = rows.length,
        n = rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
        var r = tableel.insertRow(-1);
        for (var j=0; j<m; j++)
            r.appendChild(rows[j].cells[0]);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<m; i++)
        tableel.deleteRow(0);
}
```

Would be much more complicated with jQuery :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var arr = [];

//Convert to multi array.
$("tr").each(function() {
  var r = arr.push([]);
  $(this).children("td").each(function() {
    arr[r - 1].push($(this).text())
  })
});

//Flip array.
var table = "<table>";
for(r=0;r<arr.length;r++) {
 table += "<tr>";
 for(c=0;c<arr[r].length;c++) {
   table += "<td>" + arr[r][c] + "</td>"; //Flipped indexes.
 }
 table += "</tr>";
}
table += "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="./mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js" ></script>
    <script src="./mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js" ></script>
    <style>
        #container{
            background-color: #330;
            min-height: 100px;
            min-width: 100px;
            position:relative;
            top:10px;
            left:15px;
        }
        #container .elerc {
            border: 1px solid black;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .inncell {
            display: inline-block;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;

        }
    </style>
    <script>

        window.addEvent('domready',function(){

            var r= $$('.c1').length;
            var c=$$('.r1').length;
            var mx_last_w = 0, mx_last_h = 0;

            for(var i=1; i<=r; i++){

                var  mx_h = 0;

                $$('.r'+i+' .inncell').each(function(el){
                    var cur_h = el.getComputedSize();
                    if(cur_h.totalHeight > mx_h){
                        mx_h = cur_h.totalHeight;
                    }
                });

                console.log(mx_h);

                $$('.r'+i).each(function(el){
                    //el.set('tween', {transition: Fx.Transitions.Elastic.easeOut});
                    //el.tween('height', mx_h);
                    //el.tween('top', mx_last_h);

                    el.setStyle('height', mx_h);
                    el.setStyle('top', mx_last_h);
                    el.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
                });
                mx_last_h += mx_h;
            }

            for(var j=1; j<=c; j++){

                var  mx_w = 0;

                $$('.c'+j+' .inncell').each(function(el){
                    var cur_w = el.getComputedSize();
                    if(cur_w.totalWidth > mx_w){
                        mx_w = cur_w.totalWidth;
                    }
                });

                console.log(mx_w);

                $$('.c'+j).each(function(el){

                    el.set('tween', {transition: Fx.Transitions.Elastic.easeOut});
                    //el.tween('width', mx_w);
                    el.tween('left', mx_last_w);

                    el.setStyle('width', mx_w);
                    //el.setStyle('left', mx_last_w);
                    el.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
                });
                mx_last_w += mx_w;
            }

            document.id('container').addEvent('click',function(){

                $$('elerc').each(function(el){
                    el.setStyle('height','auto');
                    el.setStyle('width','auto');
                    el.setStyle('display','inline-block');
                });

                var r= $$('.c1').length;
                var c=$$('.r1').length;

                var mx_last_w = 0, mx_last_h = 0;

                for(var i = 1; i<=r; i++){
                    $$('.r'+i).each(function(el){
                        el.addClass('tr'+i);
                        el.removeClass('r'+i);
                    });
                }
                for(var j=1; j<=c; j++){
                    $$('.c'+j).each(function(el){
                        el.addClass('r'+j);
                        el.removeClass('c'+j);
                    });
                }

                for(var k = 1; k<=r; k++){
                    $$('.tr'+k).each(function(el){
                        el.addClass('c'+k);
                        el.removeClass('tr'+k);
                    });
                }

                for(var i=1; i<=c; i++){

                    var  mx_h = 0;

                    $$('.r'+i+' .inncell').each(function(el){

                        var cur_h = el.getComputedSize();
                        if(cur_h.totalHeight > mx_h){
                            mx_h = cur_h.totalHeight;
                        }
                    });

                    console.log(mx_h);

                    $$('.r'+i).each(function(el){

                        //el.set('tween', {transition: Fx.Transitions.Elastic.easeOut});
                        //el.tween('height', mx_h);
                        //el.tween('top', mx_last_h);

                        el.setStyle('height', mx_h);
                        el.setStyle('top', mx_last_h);
                        el.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
                    });
                    mx_last_h += mx_h;
                }

                for(var j=1; j<=r; j++){

                    var  mx_w = 0;

                    $$('.c'+j+' .inncell').each(function(el){
                        var cur_w = el.getComputedSize();
                        if(cur_w.totalWidth > mx_w){
                            mx_w = cur_w.totalWidth;
                        }
                    });

                    console.log(mx_w);

                    $$('.c'+j).each(function(el){

                        el.set('tween', {transition: Fx.Transitions.Elastic.easeOut});
                        //el.tween('width', mx_w);
                        el.tween('left', mx_last_w);

                        el.setStyle('width', mx_w);
                        //el.setStyle('left', mx_last_w);
                        el.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
                    });
                    mx_last_w += mx_w;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="elerc r1 c1"><div class="inncell">name1</div></div> <div class="elerc r1 c2"><div class="inncell"><div style="">12<br/>34</div></div></div> <div class="elerc r1 c3"><div class="inncell"><img src="img02-hover.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;"/></div></div>
        <div class="elerc r2 c1"><div class="inncell">name2</div></div> <div class="elerc r2 c2"><div class="inncell">22</div></div> <div class="elerc r2 c3"><div class="inncell"><img src="img01-hover.jpg" style="height: 50px;width: 70px;" /></div></div>
    </div>
```